# Basic convolution of two sound files

Tags: convolution

I'm wondering if anyone has any simple methods for convolving two audio files?

This used to be very simple with Audition 3.0, but they have removed the feature in CS6 (very happy to be proved wrong if I am, but I can't find it). I know how to do this sort of thing in Max, but need a more off-the-shelf solution. Free or open source is even better.

Just to confirm, I'm not talking about convolution reverb here, but basic two file, sample by sample convolution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Soundhack..

http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/5891/soundhack

Old school bit of kit. The dude that programs it is awesome too real friendly guy. User manual can be found here

http://emu.music.ufl.edu/sndhckdoc/SndHckDoc.html

Comment: Thanks, with a bit of fiddling around this seems to be doing the trick. I've only recently had a mac and soundhack has been on my to-do list to get round to.

Answer (score 2):

agree with Danny.Q, soundhack is the way to go provided you have access to an OSX machine.

If you have access to max/MSP you might want to look at this http://www.cycling74.com/docs/max5/refpages/msp-ref/buffir~.html object (see the example near the bottom).

I have recently completed a series of command line programs that do sample by sample convolution for uni which sounds like exactly what you need, much simpler than soundhack but cross platform. Once they're marked they'll be on github.

Answer (score 2):

LA Convolver... free and useful AU: http://audio.lernvall.com/

Comment: BTW... Convolution reverb is just a convolution plug-in with specific sounds for convolution (impulse responses recorded in a space). IF (and not all do) the reverb allows you to load any sound file as an impulse, the result will be convolution of the two files. 

Answer (score 1):

The pfft~ object it Max/MSP makes this very simple.

Answer (score 0):

If you know Max/msp it's very straight forward. Just Transform your samples with fft, than multiply them and make an inverse fft of it, and you've got it. cheers.